# what geometric object is represented (in the complex plane) by the solution of an equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The solution to the equation:

```
       _
       z = 2/z
```

can be described as a geometric object, which?

anyone know how to go about this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: What is $\overline{z}z$, algebraically and geometrically?

Comment: Hint: 
$\overline z=2/z$ is equivalent to $\overline zz=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $z$ as $x+iy$, then $\overline{z}=x-iy$, so equation $\overline{z}=\frac{2}{z}$ is equal $z\overline{z}=2$ and $(x-iy)(x+iy)=x^2+y^2=2$, it's a circle.

Answer (score 1):

$$\overline{z}=\frac{2}{z} \Rightarrow \overline{z}z=2 \Rightarrow |z|^2=2$$

Setting $z=x+y i$ we have the following:

$$|z|^2=2 \Rightarrow |x+yi|^2=2 \Rightarrow (x+yi)(\overline{x+yi})=2 \Rightarrow (x+yi)(x-yi)=2 \Rightarrow x^2+y^2=2$$

$x^2+y^2=2$ is a circle with center at $(0,0)$ and with radius $\sqrt{2}$.